# Proving a series is convergent

Tags: analysis

Prove $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac {3^{n/2}}{2^n}$$ converges and find it's sum.

Attempt:

$$\left|\frac {\frac{3^{(n+1)/2}}{2^{n+1}}} {\frac{3^{n/2}}{2^n}}\right| =\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt3}{2} = \frac{\sqrt3}{2}$$

Since $L < 1$, the original series indeed converges by the ratio test.

Does this count as a "proof"? I kind of just solved it with knowledge from my calc 2 class. Also could I get a refresher in finding the sum of a series? It's been awhile since my calc 2 class.

Comment: Yes, this suffices, although for finding the sum, you will need the geometric series formula (and this formula applies in the finite case, which could have been another proof of convergence).

Comment: Yeah you essentially have: $\sum_1^\infty \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^n$ which clearly converges because it's a geometric series (where $|p| < 1$).